# Run powershell or python using power bi

Tags: python, powershell, powerbi

I want to allow the user to run an SQL job using a power bi report or button. I have developed the code using both Python and Powershell but I wasn't able to make the user run the code from the Powerbi button. Is this possible? if not any other way to achieve this?

Comment: This might be helpful for a starting point: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/visuals/develop-circle-card and looking for to execute the code when the button is clicked in PowerShell or Python. Might need to set DB access accordingly and create a login/credential too, I'm not sure how that works. I like putting logic in an SQL stored proc, and then having the button, etc. execute that SP with only execute access to it at the SQL level for example. I'm not much of a developer there though, just helped a bunch of them in a former IT life.

Comment: And here maybe these too to extend on that a little: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-buttons?tabs=powerbi-desktop, https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Running-python-script-with-Power-BI-button/td-p/2378226, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/powerbi/

Comment: You'll need to do this with a Power App embedded into the PBI report, the native PBI button will not do it.